# how to post a form data to controller using GET method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

my view:

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/frontend/main_con/temp">
    <input type="text" name="temp">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
function temp(){
    echo $_GET['temp'];
}
```

i cant able to reach this function and i got an error

An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

So, how to pass form data in controller using GET method?
thanx in advance.

Comment: I'm just curious why you would ever need to use GET over POST to retrieve values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

ONLY worked for me after I added the following line to applications/config/config.php:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

Answer (score 8):

View:

```
<form action="<?=site_url('controller_name/function_name);?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="temp">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Controller

```
class controller_name extends CI_Controller{

   function function_name(){
      echo $this->input->get('temp');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error go to [this line](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/application/config/config.php#L129). I personally think, that this is a mistake by design, because black-listing symbols from URI would be much better then white-listing.

As for `GET` variables .. you would have to use `<form method="get" action="/what/ever/">`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use [$this->input->get('temp');](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: why? according to my knowledge every form must be posting through "post" and "get" method in php.

Comment: I must not understand "get" that well. When i'm working in CI and post form data, i always access it with the CI method `$this->input->post('temp');`.